# Why would I get "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing'" on solution first launch?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly, azure-application-insights, system.diagnostics

I have an Asp.Net MVC project that uses Application Insights for diagnostics, with a dependency on `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`. Recently, whenever I first open the solution in VS2019 and run it with Ctrl-F5, I get a YSOD with `'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing'`

The fix is simple: I delete the `bin` and `obj` folders, clean, rebuild, then Ctrl-F5 - the project will run successfully, and I won't experience the error again this editing session - only closing and reopening VS2019 will cause it to recur.

I'm running the Preview track of VS2019 - current `v.16.4.0 Preview 2.0` and it seems to me that this error began after the last Preview upgrade. I think I probably updated `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` nugets around the same time, though, so it might have been that (and I don't have time at the moment to step back and see).

It's a minor annoyance, but does anyone know why this is happening? And what can I do to stop it?

Comment: Have you checked the compatibility between VS2019 and the Application Insights nuget? Is there a pre-release version of the App Insights nuget that is compatible with VS2019?

Comment: Good thinking. There is a beta of the nuget, but nothing in the release notes to suggest VS2019-Preview compatibility (or nothing that I can see).

Comment: Lazy devs I guess :) You can always install the nuget preview and try.

Comment: application insights sdk is not relying on any particular version of visual studio, so there are no betas to try with new visual studio.